# Node.js not finding Axios body request params

Tags: node.js, rest, http, axios

I have a Node.js API that takes in a name and gives a 422 validation error.

```
// Express is setup with bodyParser:
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('files'))

...

// API:
app.post('/test',
[
  body('name').exists(),
],
async (req, res, next) => {
  try{ 
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
      return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    return res.status(200).send('Your name is ' + req.body.name);

  }catch(error){
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }
}
```

I access this with Axios:

```
const rb = {
  name : 'John', 
} 

const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  params: {
    name : 'John'
  }
}

axios.post(url, rb, config)
.then((result) => {
  callback('Success', result);
})
.catch((err) => {
  callback('Oops!', err);
});
```

I'm getting back the first 422, my 'name' parameter isn't getting resolved by Node.js.  It's not in req.body

Am i sending the wrong request through Axios?  It works in postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rb` should be the object that gets passed as request body:

```
axios.post(url, { name : 'John' }, config)
```

The `params` configuration option is used to pass query/URL parameters (accessible through `req.query`).

Given that it works in Postman, I assume that your Express server is using the correct body parser ([`express.urlencoded`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded)).

Comment: I have tried the edited code above too, i get the same validationResult errors

Comment: they were in req.query, not req.body!  makes sense!  Thanks for the tip

Comment: That's actually not correct. The reason that they were in `req.query` is because you're setting `params` in `config`, but that's not how it should work. Have you tried completely removing `params`?